# Passing a Guid to SQL code within Asp.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net

This SQL code is in the Asp.Net code itself so how can I set the `WHERE` to equal the `Guid` which I have passed over in the requestQuery String? 
E.g I want to put something like `WHERE tblEntrants.compID = Request.QueryString("Comp")` but obviously I can't. The `Guid` in the QueryString need passing in to this SQL query somehow. I'm fairly new to all this so if anyone can help I would much appreciate it.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSEntrants" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblEntrants.accountID, tblEntrants.compID, tblaccounts.accountID, tblaccounts.contactName, tblEntrants.paid
        FROM tblAccounts INNER JOIN
            tblEntrants ON tblAccounts.accountID = tblEntrants.accountID  
        WHERE tblEntrants.compID =  ?????????????????
        ORDER BY tblEntrants.accountID DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

Comment: You should avoid using SqlDataSource. It doesn't allow you to follow the [Separation of Concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Your data should come from a separate data layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked out how to do this. You can directly set a querystring parameter like this..

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSEntrants" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT tblEntrants.accountID, tblEntrants.compID, tblaccounts.accountID, tblaccounts.contactName, tblaccounts.skypeUserName, tblEntrants.paid
        FROM tblAccounts INNER JOIN
        tblEntrants ON tblAccounts.accountID = tblEntrants.accountID  
        WHERE tblEntrants.compID = @Event_ID
        ORDER BY tblEntrants.accountID DESC">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="compID" Name="Event_ID" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

All works fine, thanks for reading.